# Cannot run any project in Android Studio 0.8.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I cannot run any project. I created a default project with an acitivity and when i try to run it I get this error.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
    > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
        C:\androidstudio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\dx.bat --dex --num-threads=4 --output C:\projects\app\build\intermediates\dex\debug C:\projects\app\build\intermediates\classes\debug C:\projects\app\build\intermediates\dependency-cache\debug
    Error Code:
        1
    Output:
        The system cannot find the path specified.
        The system cannot find the path specified.
        The system cannot find the path specified.
```

any dependency it tries to copy to dex/debug im guessing, but fails to do so. 
Any ideas?

Comment: this solved it for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748085/android-studio-giving-us-following-error/21752326#21752326

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should double check that the path `C:\androidstudio\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\dx.bat` does indeed exist. It could be that your SDK configuration is pointing at an invalid directory (though that's unlikely, given how far you're getting in the compilation/build process).

After that, this looks very similar to [a similar error on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21550897/unable-to-locate-a-java-runtime-android-studio-robolectric), so you might try the proposed solution there, which is to run `gradlew.bat --stop` using the Gradle wrapper script that should be in the root of your project and then try to compile again.